# NoStore is not setting Cache-Control to no-store

Tags: caching, asp.net-core

We have used `[ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]` on our `AccountController.Login` action.

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseCache(NoStore = true)]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

According to the documentation:

> `NoStore` overrides most of the other properties. When this property is set to `true`, the `Cache-Control` header will be set to `"no-store"`.

In a new private Firefox window, when we navigate to `~/Account/Login`, we receive the following response headers.

```
Cache-Control:"no-cache"
Content-Type:"text/html; charset=utf-8"
Date:"Mon, 26 Dec 2016 21:50:27 GMT"
Pragma:"no-cache"
Server:"Kestrel"
Transfer-Encoding:"chunked"
```

We are using ASP.NET Core 1.1.0. How do we set the `Cache-Control` header to `no-store`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that ASP.NET Core anti-forgery [nukes all user set headers and adds its own](https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/blob/3fc090e2fee47884af7968031e40876fcb6549ae/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/Internal/DefaultAntiforgery.cs#L370-L379). To overcome that, we added our own `IHtmlGenerator`.

```
// Startup.cs
services.AddSingleton<
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.IHtmlGenerator, 
    OurHacks.HtmlGeneratorHack>();

// HtmlGeneratorHack.cs (subsclasses DefaultHtmlGenerator)
public override IHtmlContent GenerateAntiforgery(ViewContext viewContext)
{
    var result = base.GenerateAntiforgery(viewContext);

    viewContext
        .HttpContext
        .Response
        .Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] 
            = "no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store";

     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any page that implements form tag helpers, i.e. asp-action, asp-controller, will clear out the cache-control settings.   I'm just adding this because it might not have been clear from the answer above.

This has been incredibly frustrating and I hope this answers helps someone.

Comment: This would be better as a comment instead of an answer.